# Is CBT-based anger management effective?

Tags: behavior, therapy, cbt

I have no doubt that some (aggressive) medication will definitely work in cutting people's anger-outburst potential. But is the usual CBT-based anger management class effective? There's a [2013 BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-22264123) which says the systematic evidence isn't too convincing, although (of course) practitioners say it works if the patient has enough commitment.

In particular, most doubt seem to be whether such class-based approach can affect real-life "heat of the moment" events/outburst. So what does the scientific evidence on this look like? Are there substantial well-designed studies on this, are there enough studies for meta-analyses etc.?

Comment: Would the answers in https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1977 help with your question?

Comment: @ChrisRogers: there's only a deleted answer there which mentioned anger in passing, so no, it doesn't help much.

Comment: The the last section of the first answer (shortfalls of CBT) may cover it as it is talking about CBT for all human problems.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question as to the quality (and quantify) of research on CBT-for-anger-management.

Comment: @ChrisRogers The linked answer was [heavily criticized for being too broad](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/1977/cognitive-behavioral-therapy-limitations#comment4864_1977), even though it attracted a lot of up votes. The OP has since stated that _"I'd like to focus on people with narcissistic mothers for this question"_, which unfortunately never got made clear in the question. I think your lengthy/broad answer there gives a clear example of why a narrower scope in these questions are needed. As such, I agree with Fizz this is a separate question.